# How do I target a specific day of the current month with DateTime::modify?

Tags: php, datetime

I need to be able to set a DateTime object to a certain day of the current month. I can obviously do this by getting the current month and creating a new DateTime, or checking the current day and creating a DateInterval object to modify the DateTime, but I want to just give plain text arguments to DateTime::modify.

I'm looking for something like:

```
$datetime->modify('10th day this month');
```

but this gives me an error like

> PHP Warning:  DateTime::modify(): Failed to parse time string (10th day this month) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character in php shell code on line 1

and I don't seem able to find the correct construction of the sentence to make PHP play nicely.

Comment: Please upvote this bug request > https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50249

Comment: Done, although it doesn't seem to have moved in 3 years.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It isn't possible to get the Xth day of a given month directly, but you can achieve this with a simple workaround:

```
$datetime->modify('last day of previous month')->modify('+10 day');
```

Another alternative would be:

```
$datetime->format('Y-m-10');
```

Comment: Fair enough, pity it can't be done directly when this demonstrates how easy it would be to implement. I think I prefer to jump to the first day of the current month before adding the days, although that's just my preference.

Comment: @shanethehat: That would add one extra day to the result. See [this demo](https://eval.in/72362).

Comment: @vascowhite: Yeah, that's another way to do it. I think it's more relevant since the question is tagged with `datetime`.

Comment: Which gave me an idea to avoid calling modify() twice :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/20150497/212940

Comment: 1. if you want to change a date twice, mind to use `clone`
2. the correct way of modifying that date should be `modify('last day of last month')`...

Answer (score 3):

If you must use DateTime::modify() then this workaround may suit you:-

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->modify($date->format('Y-m-10'));
```

Although it probably isn't any better than Amal's answer, I offer it here just as an alternative that avoids the double call.

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/UhT15)

Comment: Why would you create new object, why don't you just use the same one, like `$date->modify($date->format('Y-m-10'));`? IMO `->setDate()` is nicer solution.

Answer (score 2):

I found this saves a few microseconds to use `setDate()` and `format()` to extract the current year and month to satisfy setDate's 3 arguments (but kinda verbose)

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->setDate($date->format('Y'), $date->format('m'), 10);
```